# PHP and Oracle - Getting &#146; rather than single quote with insert

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

I am writing an engine so that I can read an RSS feed and post into my Oracle database however when getting an apostrophe from the RSS feed, and inserting into the database, I'm getting `&#146;` when looking in the database after `INSERT`however the initial string in PHP is `’`. Is there any way in the Oracle insert to ensure that it stays as `’` rather than changing to `&#146;`

I have tried using

```
$variable = "Someone’s String"


$sql = "INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (q'[" . $variable. "]')"
```

I am also having the same issue with the characters `£` and `–` which are displaying as `&#163;` and `&#150;`

However this doesn't seem to work - Please could you shed some light on the situation

Comment: How do you get assured that in PHP this string is `’`?

Comment: var_dump and echo both say it is

Comment: So you look at the browser-rendered output, right? Try to _view page source_, I’m pretty sure there is HTML entity.

Comment: Ahh okay, in the page source it does display as `&#146;` do you know a way in PHP to make this correct? Or a way to change it with Oracle

Comment: That means your RSS feed has html entities. You should deal with it.

Comment: Thank you for that... Now "How" do I deal with it, I am not able to change the RSS feed itself, I will need to change it with a function or something but cannot afford to go through each character in a switch statement to change all of them, is there a PHP or Oracle function that allows me to do this already built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RSS feed contains entities, so you need to convert them to their string representations. [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) comes to the rescue:

```
INSERT INTO table (column) 
VALUES (html_entity_decode($variable, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1))
```

Please note that the result drastically depends on **flags** (second parameter.) Hope this helps.

Comment: This definitely works. It looks like you did not follow the link I provided and did not check the documentation. To encode quotes you need to pass additional parameter to the function.

Comment: I had to use the ENT_XML1 flag in order for it to work but the function itself did so accepting your answer, could you update it to use that flag so that its fully correct please

Comment: I appended the notice about “result is depending on flags.”

Comment: Just as a side note question - Do you know why `&#39;` isn't changing like `&#146;` even though they are both apostrophes, is there another flag that's needed?

Comment: Nevermind I'd forgot to add the flags to my second use of the html_entity_decode... My error